# node and taxonomy module Update #7006 and #7005 problem

Tags: updating

I upgrade my Drupal6 to Drupal7.

When everything was done.

The error messages as below came out.

***The following updates returned messages***

***node module
Update #7006***

```
Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table field_data_body already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /home/mysite/domains/site.com/public_html/includes/database/schema.inc).
```

***taxonomy module
Update #7005***

```
Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table taxonomy_update_7005 already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /home/mysite/domains/site.com/public_html/includes/database/schema.inc).
```

How should I fix it?

I have reupdate the module but same problems.

Comment: Did you make a backup before you performed the upgrade? If so, I would restore the backup, make sure tables `field_data_body` & `taxonomy_update_7005` don't exist in your database, and perform the backup again.

Comment: @ShawnConn Where is the location of the field_data_body & taxonomy_update_7005 in database?

Comment: I don't understand by "location", does your database client not show those tables in your database?

Comment: @ShawnConn Do you mean look into myphpadmin and delete the field_data_body & taxonomy_update_7005 ?

Comment: You should try restoring from a backup and try the upgrade again, if possible. If that's not an option (you really should have a backup for something like this), then removing the `taxonomy_update_7005` & `field_data_body` tables and attempting the upgrade is a way to get around those errors (both are exceptions with creating tables that already exist).